# Mocking a test methods that are in the same interface and is called within

Tags: c#, mocking

Lets say i have an interface with the following members

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Employee TestMethodA();
    Employee TestMethodB();
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public Employee TestMethodA()
    {
        return new Employee() {Id = 10, Name = "Montu Pradhan"};
    }

    public Employee TestMethodB()
    {
        var emp = TestMethodA();
        return emp;
    }   
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then i need to test the method MethodB by mocking MethodA. I have the following fixture but the control still goes into the MethodA. I am using JustMock for the testing framework.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInterfaceMock()
    {
        var pensionMock = Mock.Create<DataService>();
        Mock.Arrange<Employee>(() => pensionMock.TestMethodA())
        .Returns(new Employee() {Id = 101,Name = "Mock Employee"});
        var result = pensionMock.TestMethodB();
       Assert.AreEqual(result.Name, "Mock Employee");
       Assert.AreEqual(result.Id, "Mock Employee");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can mock MethodA if its Virtual. Then the debugger would return the object that has in the Reuturns() block in Mock.Arrange....

Answer (score 0):

You can not mock `TestMethodA()` since it's in the same class that you are testing - you can make `TestMethodA()` virtual, create a derived class that overrides `TestMethodA()` (mock it) and test `TestMethodB()` that is unchanged in your tester-class.

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public virtual Employee TestMethodA()
    {
        return new Employee() {Id = 10, Name = "Montu Pradhan"};
    }

}

public class TestableDataService : DataService
{
    private Employee e;
    public TestableDataService(Employee returningEmployee)
    {
        this.e = returningEmployee;
    }

    public override Employee TestMethodA()
    {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Now you can test `TestMethodB()`:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInterfaceMock()
    {
        var testableSut = new TestableDataService(new Employee() {Id = 101,Name = "Mock Employee"});
        var result = testableSut.TestMethodB();
       Assert.AreEqual(result.Name, "Mock Employee");
       Assert.AreEqual(result.Id, "101");
    }
}
```

Another option would be to Split `IDataService` into two interfaces containig `TestMethodA` and `TestMethodB` (depends on design decistions e.g. cohesion) and then inject the interface containing `TestMethodA` into the class - then you can mock it as you wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr.Wombat.

In real Application acts as the same scenario. I had to setup a lot of stuff for MethodA and use it. i was able to mock it if it was virtual..

Most of the Mock frameworks do not mock the non-Virtual methods. The options are JustMock Commercial license which can Mock the non - Virtual Method.